# how to add index.php in codeigniter with every anchor

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have developed a shopping cart and have removed index.php using .htaccess file but now my client is asking me to show him the site on free web hosting first i have tried 000webhost but they do not support .htaccess file hence i moved to orgfree.com it also dont support .htaccess file than i remove .htaccess file and it created a problem because now i need to put `index.php` infront of every url but now i am consfuse that how can i add `index.php` with every achor doing this with every link manually will be a very huge process because the project is so big so there might be a solution for adding index.php to every anchor in `codeigniter` .

Here are some setting i have done so far please suggest me or help me adding `index.php` to every anchor

In `Config.php`

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

**Before my anchor were like that**

```
<li class="active"><a href="views">Home</a></li>
```

But after removing .htaccess file i need to put index.php with every anchor manually which is headace and i cant do it please show me the shortest path to add index.php with every link or anchor.

```
<li class="active"><a href="index.php/views">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: It's a bit late now, but if you had used `<a href="<?php echo site_url('views');?>">Home</a>` for your anchors you would have solved this problem almost instantly. That said, your only choice now is to change your URLs manually (or find a host that allows .htaccess).

Comment: yea dear i have tried alot if i wanna put index.php to every anchor i need to $config['base_url'] = 'http://sitedomain/index.php/'; but it disturb my design and other structure in my site i am really disturb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Nicolas and J Young are correct. you should use URL helper to avoid any trouble in the future. But since you want to a quick-fix, how about fixing link urls via JS

i'll give you a jquery example,

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
  
   $('a').each(function(){
     var newUrl = 'index.php/'+$(this).attr('href');
     $(this).attr('href', newUrl)
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="view">you link</a>
```

Include above code into your views

Comment: i Appreciated your work thanks alot you have solved my problem its working fine now but still having some routing problem but you have reduced my work thats why i am accepting your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you now have to change it mannually, but start using Codeigniter functions in [URL Helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

Take a look at base_url() and site_url() they are very usefull when you need to be prepared for changes like yours.

For example, in your code you can put:

```
<li class="active"><a href="<?php print base_url(); ?>views">Home</a></li>
```

or

```
<li class="active"><a href="<?php print site_url('views'); ?>views">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: Duran the way you showed me is again a huge manuall entry to my website i want it to do in short way anyhow thanks

Answer (score 0):

In config set your base_url to this

```
$config['base_url']    = "your_site_url/index.php/";
```

Comment: but it disturb my design and other structure than

Comment: i have tried this before your answer and work correctly but it has another problem it disturb my design than because i am loading all the .js and .css file using base_url()